# LDAP: backup with slapcat vs ldapsearch

Tags: openldap, slapd

Used: `openldap-servers-2.4.23-34.el6_5.1.x86_64`

Task: create script for `crontab` to create scheduled database full backup.

1) `slapcat` - create file in in the default format, Berkeley DB.

2) `slapcat` can be done while `slapd` running (if `bdb/hdb` database used).

3) To restore file after `slapcat` - must be used `slapadd` (not `ldapadd`).

4) `slapcat/add` doesn't require password.

5) `slapadd` can be done only when `slapd` stopped.

Example:

```
 $ slapcat -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -b "dc=db_1" -l db_1_backup.ldif
 $ slapadd -l db_1_backup.ldif
```

Instead of `slapcat/add` - let's took a look at `ldapsearch/add`:

1) `ldapsearch` - creates file with almost same information as `slapcat`;

2) `ldapadd` - can use file from `ldapsearch`, doesn't require `slapd` to be stopped;

3) `ldapadd/search` - requires password.

Example:

```
 $ ldapsearch -D "cn=root,dc=db_1" -W -b "dc=db_1" "dc=db_1" -LLL > db_1_backup2.ldif
 $ ldapadd -x -D "cn=root,dc=db_1" -W -f db_1_backup2.ldif
```

So - question is:

1) Am I missing anything in this tools description?

2) What else is difference between `ldapadd/slapadd` and `ladpsearch/slapcat`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good summary, some additional points:

- `slapcat` dumps from whatever the (local) direct storage backend is, it need not be Berkeley (hdb or bdb), it also works with [OLC](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html) (`cn=config`). It dumps to [LDIF format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849). (By direct I mean directly managed by OpenLDAP, not for example an SQL backend, even if its stored locally.)
- `ldapadd` requires that slapd *is* running, `slapadd` requires that it *is not* running
- `ldapsearch` requires that `slapd` *is* running, `slapcat` doesn't care if it's running with a BDB backend, as you noted

In short:

- `slapcat` is the way to get a good backup that you can restore quickly, albeit with downtime on the master (you can work around this with various types of replication set up). This is what you should use for a general backup, and pre-upgrade backups.
- `ldapsearch` (without `+`) will get you a *portable* backup you can probably load with little difficulty into any other directory server, but it will only be a viable restore in a simple OpenLDAP set up (no replication, no special overlays, no rewriting), and if you don't care about preserving UUID/create/modify meta-data. You'll need any extra schema files that go along with your data too.
- `ldapadd` (using its other identity `ldapmodify`) can be used to easily apply LDAP modifications (object modify, delete and rename) which are not feasible or possible with `slapadd`/`slapcat` alone

For most admins the main considerations arise from the slightly different contents of the LDIF in each case, and the requirement for `slapd` to be running (or not). The more important differences are:

1. `slapcat` is faster because it simply dumps the database, skipping the LDAP protocol overheads,  authentication, access control, object and time limits, overlays; and it does not search according to the LDAP hierarchy.
2. `slapadd` is faster (again, no LDAP protocol overheads), and in the case that you are restoring a known-good backup you can run in *quick mode* (`-q`) to speed up large imports. You can also disable schema checking (`-s`), though note than small changes in schema or data validation between OpenLDAP versions are not unheard of.
3. `slapcat` is limited to local databases, it will not cross over to other directories (e.g. with `back-ldap`, `back-meta`) the way `ldapsearch` will. The same applies to `slapadd`/`ldapadd`.
4. `ldapsearch` will return dynamic attributes which are not stored in a backend, e.g. `hasSubordinates` or those maintained by overlays (e.g. `slapo-memberof`). You will have problems loading these with `ldapadd` (e.g. operational attributes with no-user-modification). Rewriting (slapo-rwm) may also distort `ldapsearch`'s view of the directory contents.
5. `slapcat` includes internal (operational) attributes, if you are using replication these attributes are critical. With replication then you are somewhat less dependent on backups, but if you use `ldapadd` to reload your master, every object will be *recreated* by replication (changed `entryUUID` `entryCSN`)
   Although you can include operational attributes by using the special "+" attribute with `ldapsearch` (or `allop` overlay), *this is not the same thing as `slapcat`*, see the previous point for why this is so.
   These attributes also include create/modify DN and timestamps, which may be important to some applications.
6. because `slapcat` does not observe the LDAP hierarchy (implied ordering), there's no guarantee that its data ordering is going to be viable with `ldapadd` - i.e. even if you strip out the operational attributes, `ldapadd` can complain because sub-ordinates may appear before their superiors (parents).  The LDAP specs require a parent to exist, but also leave the search result ordering undefined in this respect. See Howard's comment below, OpenLDAP's `slapadd` silently supports unordered data for some backends. In a pinch you may be able to repeatedly use `slapadd` with the continue on error option (`-c`) until all the "out of order" parents are created, stopping when you no longer receive any error code 32 (no such object, meaning missing parent) and receive only code 68 (already exists) for every object.
7. `ldapadd` is subject to the LDAP rules and overlays, e.g. referential integrity, ppolicy (password policy)
8. `slapcat` prefers to use base-64 encoded attribute values for at least userPassword (indicated with `::` after the attribute name)
9. `ldapsearch` has more options for LDIF formatting, and writing large attributes to separate files. It may also handle [referrals](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.1.10) and [aliases](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-2.6).

Comment: LDAP result order is undefined. Both slapcat and ldapsearch may return entries in arbitrary order, neither output is guaranteed to be in suitable order for use with ldapadd. slapadd's bdb/hdb/mdb drivers have special workarounds to process input in arbitrary order, ldapadd doesn't.

Comment: `slapcat` returns entries in database (backend) order, which may or may not be well-defined. `ldapsearch` by default returns in the order the server replies, with OpenLDAP there is the choice of client-side sort (e.g. `-S ""`) or server-side sort control (e.g. `-E sss`, if supported, and subject to some minor config & schema related bear traps). The [spec says](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4511#section-4.5.2) the search results may be in any order. An implementation could define a default order, most people assume the default is "parent before child", only OpenDS documents this, AFAIK.

Comment: The search result order in OpenLDAP is intentionally undocumented. Since the spec already says results may be in any order, client software must not rely on any particular order. Sorting of the results can of course be done but that requires a lot more resources and typically isn't interesting when doing a full backup.

Database order is relatively meaningless given the possibility of subtree renames moving branches to new DIT locations.

Answer (score 1):

`slapcat` does not work if you have overlays, e.g. `memberOf`. So if you do a `slapcat` / `slapadd` cycle membership overlays will no longer work.